# Does every open cover of a two dimensional continuous curve has a countable sub-cover?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

As we know every open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ has a countable sub-cover. Also, a two dimension line is isomorphic to the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. Can we apply the proof of having $\mathbb{R}$ a countable sub-cover for every open cover to find a countable sub-cover for a two dimensional continuous curve?

Comment: A continuous image of $\mathbb R$ in **any** topological space is $\sigma$-compact, therefore any cover of that image by open sets will have a countable subcover.

Comment: A continuous image of a Lindelöf space is Lindelöf, and as stated, $\Bbb R$ is Lindelöf. @bof $\sigma$-compactness is true, but not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb R$ is Lindelöf. The continuous image of a Lindelöf space is Lindelöf (same proof essentially as the compact case), so any curve, i.e. $f[\Bbb R]$ where $f: \Bbb R \to X$ (e.g. $X$ can be $\Bbb R^2$ if you like) is continuous, is Lindelöf. QED.

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb R^n$ is second-countable, and therefore hereditarily Lindelöf. Therefore every subset of $\Bbb R^n$, be it the image of a continuous function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$ or otherwise, is Lindelöf.

Comment: Thanks @Gae. May you suggest a link/reference to see the proof of such result?

Comment: Combine [this](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Second-countability_is_hereditary) and [this](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Second-countable_implies_Lindelof).